# Example of a homogeneous space that is not linear group orbit

Tags: representation-theory, homogeneous-spaces

Give an example of a manifold $ M $ which is homogeneous (isomorphic to the quotient of a Lie group by a closed subgroup) but which is not a linear orbit. In other words, $ M $ is homogeneous but for any Lie group $ G $ any representation $ \pi: G \to GL(V) $ and any $ v \in V $ then the orbit
$$
\mathcal{O}_v:=\{ \pi(g)v:g \in G\} 
$$
is not diffeomorphic to $ M $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For compact manifolds being a linear group orbit is equivalent to being Riemannian homogeneous see

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409511/compact-linear-group-orbit-equivalent-to-linear-compact-group-orbit

so a compact linear group orbit is aspherical if and only if it is a torus. See

[Riemannian homogeneous aspherical iff flat torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4382864/riemannian-homogeneous-aspherical-iff-flat-torus?noredirect=1#comment9166212_4382864)

Every compact solvmanifold is aspherical. So every compact solvmanifold that is not a torus is an example of a homogeneous manifold that is not a linear group orbit. Example include the Klein bottle in 2d and many manifolds with flat, Nil or Solv geometry in 3d see for example

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414531/3-dimensional-solvmanifolds-and-thurston-geometries